# How to winsorize a series while preserving ranking information

Tags: python, r, statistics

I've used several winsorizing methods, including scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize, replacing outliers outside of certain percentiles, or replacing outliers outside of certain standard deviations. However, these methods will assign the same values to the outliers. When I move on to rank these data for other purposes, I've lost information about the rankings of these outliers. Is there a proper way to winsorize data without losing the ranking information?